# Invoking a web service from a CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a plugin that invokes an AX custom web service.
The web service should return a price given a product and a customer.

I am able to invoke the web service without problems outside CRM, but after including it in the plugin it stopped working.

The error message I get is:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'AxIntegrationServices.PriceDiscService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Here is the code:

```
//retrieve the entity product as the input Entity
var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

//Early bound entity
var oppProduct = new opportunityproduct(entity);
var quantity = (Decimal)oppProduct.quantity;

tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Opp with opp ID = {0}", oppProduct.opportunityid.Id.ToString());

//get the early bound opportunity containing the opportunity product
var opp = new opportunity(Helper.ActualEntity(oppProduct.opportunityid, service));
//get the early bound account entity that is the customer for the opportunity
tracingService.Trace("Retrieved, type = {0}", opp.name);
tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Account with accountID={0}", opp.customerid.Id.ToString());
Entity acc = Helper.ActualEntity(opp.customerid, service);
tracingService.Trace("Account retrieved");
var account = new account(acc);
//get the ax integration key for the account
tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Account AX key");
var accountAxKey = account.custom_axrecordid;
tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Product");
//get the early bound account entity that is the customer for the opportunity
var product = new product(Helper.ActualEntity(oppProduct.productid, service, new string[]{ "custom_axrecordid" }));
//get the integration key for the product
tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Product AX key");
var productAxKey = product.custom_axrecordid;

tracingService.Trace("Invoking web service");
PriceDiscServiceClient priceDiscServiceClient = new PriceDiscServiceClient();

CallContext callContext = new CallContext();

priceDiscServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "xxx";

priceDiscServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "yyyy!";

priceDiscServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "aaa"; 


PriceDiscServiceContract priceDiscServiceContract = priceDiscServiceClient.getPriceDiscSales(callContext, productAxKey, accountAxKey, quantity);

tracingService.Trace("Price :{0}",priceDiscServiceContract.Price);
tracingService.Trace("Markup :{0}", priceDiscServiceContract.Markup);
tracingService.Trace("PriceUnit :{0}", priceDiscServiceContract.PriceUnit);
tracingService.Trace("DiscAmount :{0}", priceDiscServiceContract.DiscAmount);
tracingService.Trace("DiscPct :{0}", priceDiscServiceContract.DiscPct);

oppProduct.priceperunit = priceDiscServiceContract.PriceUnit;



oppProduct.isproductoverridden = false;
oppProduct.ispriceoverridden = true;
```

The web service is located in the same network of the CRM environment and I am working through a VPN to connect to them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us your code wher you initialize your client? I'd suspect your solution relies on configuration provided by an app.config.

Comment: You are right. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your `PriceDiscServiceClient` constructor - it should accept a `Binding` and `EndpointAddress` so your code could look something like this:

```
 //...
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

 // configure Binding as needed (Timeout, etc.) ...

 EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointUri);
 PriceDiscServiceClient client = new PriceDiscServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
 //...
```

As James Wood already pointed out the next problem will be to populate `endpointUri` with a configurable value instead of hardcoding it into your Plugin.

I tend to prefer the plugin unsecure configration rather than roundtrip to a crm settings record for every time the plugin executes.

The [link James Wood refers to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/10/24/storing-configuration-data-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-plug-ins.aspx?Redirected=true) is exactly the solution I'd choose to configure the endpoint address Uri.

Comment: I created an XML web resource with the data I need. I fetch the data from there, I have too many steps to register to be able to use a plugin configuration

Answer (score 2):

If you code relies on configuration in the app.config as Filburt suggested then this approach is unlikely to work. When you add your plugin assembly to MSCRM the app.config is not included (its in a separate configuration file).

You wont be able to add any of the configuration in the app.config to the CRM app.config (because its not supported).

I would suggest whatever you are doing on the app.config moving into code within the plugin itself. Anything you are doing in the app.config you should be able to do in code as well.

If you need to retrieve settings values (e.g. connection strings) you might want to consider using a settings record in CRM and retrieving that information. Or alternatively using the plugins [configuration section](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/10/24/storing-configuration-data-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-plug-ins.aspx?Redirected=true).